# Web Scraping Python: Not getting wanted data from drop down menu from a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to get the data from a webpage. Here is the link https://www.cardekho.com/compare-cars. From this page, we need to scrape the comparison of the cars data tables and its specifications once we give its URL of the car models and its variants in the drop-down menu. Here is my sample code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

def job():
    url = 'https://www.cardekho.com/compare/maruti-gypsy-and-maruti-omni.htm'

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/65.0'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    stat_table_1 = soup.find_all('table')


    print(len(stat_table_1))

    tab_1 = stat_table_1[0]
    tab_2 = stat_table_1[1]
    tab_3 = stat_table_1[2]
    tab_4 = stat_table_1[3]
    tab_5 = stat_table_1[4]

    rows_tab_1 = tab_1.findAll('tr')
    rows_tab_2 = tab_2.findAll('tr')
    rows_tab_3 = tab_3.findAll('tr')
    rows_tab_4 = tab_4.findAll('tr')
    rows_tab_5 = tab_5.findAll('tr')

    csv_file_1 = open("D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/overview.csv", 'wt', encoding="utf-8", newline='')
    csv_file_2 = open("D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/engine.csv", 'wt', encoding="utf-8", newline='')
    csv_file_3 = open("D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/transmission.csv", 'wt', encoding="utf-8", newline='')
    csv_file_4 = open("D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/steering.csv", 'wt', encoding="utf-8", newline='')
    csv_file_5 = open("D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/brake_system.csv", 'wt', encoding="utf-8", newline='')

    writer_1 = csv.writer(csv_file_1)
    writer_2 = csv.writer(csv_file_2)
    writer_3 = csv.writer(csv_file_3)
    writer_4 = csv.writer(csv_file_4)
    writer_5 = csv.writer(csv_file_5)

    try:
        for row in rows_tab_1:
            csv_row = []
            for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
                csv_row.append(cell.get_text())
            writer_1.writerow(csv_row)
    finally:
        csv_file_1.close()

    try:
        for row in rows_tab_2:
            csv_row = []
            for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
                csv_row.append(cell.get_text())
            writer_2.writerow(csv_row)
    finally:
        csv_file_2.close()

    try:
        for row in rows_tab_3:
            csv_row = []
            for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
                csv_row.append(cell.get_text())
            writer_3.writerow(csv_row)
    finally:
        csv_file_3.close()

    try:
        for row in rows_tab_4:
            csv_row = []
            for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
                csv_row.append(cell.get_text())
            writer_4.writerow(csv_row)
    finally:
        csv_file_4.close()

    try:
        for row in rows_tab_5:
            csv_row = []
            for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
                csv_row.append(cell.get_text())
            writer_5.writerow(csv_row)
    finally:
        csv_file_5.close()
```

But here the problem is that I'm not getting the exact data that I need because of the URLs. Which means If I give four car models and its variants for comparison, it is randomly giving the data from that car model from the mentioned drop-down menu.

Can anyone explain how I can solve this problem & get exact data that I need from that URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing quite a bit of work to parse those tables. Pandas can do that work for you using `.read_html()`.

this will return to you a list of dataframes. Just chose the dataframes and write to csv using pandas `.to_csv()`.

If it were me, I'd condense these into a loop to iterate through these, but I left it expanded so you could see it broken down (if that's helpful)

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.cardekho.com/compare/maruti-gypsy-and-maruti-omni.htm'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
compare_cols = list(tables[0].columns[1:])

overview = tables[0]

engine = tables[1]
engine.columns = [engine.columns[0]] + compare_cols

transmision = tables[2]
transmision.columns = [transmision.columns[0]] + compare_cols

steering = tables[3]
steering.columns = [steering.columns[0]] + compare_cols

brakes_system = tables[4]
brakes_system.columns = [brakes_system.columns[0]] + compare_cols


overview.to_csv('D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/overview.csv', index=False)
engine.to_csv('D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/engine.csv', index=False)
transmision.to_csv('D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/transmision.csv', index=False)
steering.to_csv('D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/steering.csv', index=False)
brakes_system.to_csv('D:/CarDekho_Data/maruti/maruti_2/brakes_system.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (overview)
                                      Overview                        ...                                                                       Omni
0                                On Road Price                        ...                                                               Rs.3,36,883*
1                                    Fuel Type                        ...                                                                     Petrol
2                     Engine Displacement (cc)                        ...                                                                        796
3                             Available Colors                        ...                          Fantasy BlackMetallic silky silverMetallic Pea...
4                                    Body Type                        ...                                                                    Minivan
5                                    Max Power                        ...                                                            34.2bhp@5000rpm
6                                 User Reviews                        ...                                                     4.5Based on 45 Reviews
7                               Mileage (ARAI)                        ...                                                                  16.8 kmpl
8                                 Cargo Volume                        ...                                                                 210-litres
9                           Fuel Tank Capacity                        ...                                                                   35Litres
10                            Seating Capacity                        ...                                                                          5
11                           Transmission Type                        ...                                                                     Manual
12                           Offers & Discount                        ...                                                            1 OfferView now
13                     Finance Available (EMI)                        ...                                                         Rs.6,510 Check Now
14                           Insurance SaveBig                        ...                                                          Rs.17,146Know how
15                                Service Cost                        ...                                                                   Rs.2,996
16                                         NaN                        ...                                                                        NaN
17                             Air Conditioner                        ...                                                                         No
18                                   Cd Player                        ...                                                                         No
19                    Anti Lock Braking System                        ...                                                                         No
20                              Power Steering                        ...                                                                         No
21                         Power Windows Front                        ...                                                                         No
22                          Power Windows Rear                        ...                                                                         No
23                               Leather Seats                        ...                                                                         No
24                Speed Sensing Auto Door Lock                        ...                                                                         No
25             Impact Sensing Auto Door Unlock                        ...                                                                          -
26                             Air Conditioner                        ...                                                                         No
27                                      Heater                        ...                                                                         No
28                         Adjustable Steering                        ...                                                                         No
29                                  Tachometer                        ...                                                                         No
..                                         ...                        ...                                                                        ...
47                       Adjustable Headlights                        ...                                                                        Yes
48                            Fog Lights Front                        ...                                                                         No
49                             Fog Lights Rear                        ...                                                                         No
50  Power Adjustable Exterior Rear View Mirror                        ...                                                                         No
51    Manually Adjustable Ext Rear View Mirror                        ...                                                                        Yes
52           Electric Folding Rear View Mirror                        ...                                                                         No
53                          Rain Sensing Wiper                        ...                                                                         No
54                           Rear Window Wiper                        ...                                                                         No
55                          Rear Window Washer                        ...                                                                         No
56                        Rear Window Defogger                        ...                                                                         No
57                                Wheel Covers                        ...                                                                         No
58                                Alloy Wheels                        ...                                                                         No
59                               Power Antenna                        ...                                                                         No
60                                Tinted Glass                        ...                                                                         No
61                                Rear Spoiler                        ...                                                                         No
62                Removable Or Convertible Top                        ...                                                                         No
63                                Roof Carrier                        ...                                                                         No
64                                    Sun Roof                        ...                                                                         No
65                                   Moon Roof                        ...                                                                         No
66                                Side Stepper                        ...                                                                         No
67    Outside Rear View Mirror Turn Indicators                        ...                                                                         No
68                          Integrated Antenna                        ...                                                                         No
69                               Chrome Grille                        ...                                                                         No
70                              Chrome Garnish                        ...                                                                         No
71                             Smoke Headlamps                        ...                                                                         No
72                                   Roof Rail                        ...                                                                         No
73                                    Lighting                        ...                                                                         No
74                                Trunk Opener                        ...                                                                      Lever
75                         Additional Features                        ...                          2 Speed Windshield WiperFront And Rear Thermop...
76                          Heated Wing Mirror                        ...                                                                         No

[77 rows x 3 columns]
```

...

```
print (engine)
                 Engine                 ...                                                  Omni
0                  Type                 ...                                        In-Line Engine
1          Displacement                 ...                                                   796
2             Max Power                 ...                                       34.2bhp@5000rpm
3                  Year                 ...                                                  2010
4            Max Torque                 ...                                          59Nm@2500rpm
5           Description                 ...                   0.8-litre 34.2bhp 6V In-Line Engine
6        No Of Cylinder                 ...                                                     3
7   Valves Per Cylinder                 ...                                                     2
8   Valve Configuration                 ...                                                  SOHC
9    Fuel Supply System                 ...                                                  MPFI
10         Bore XStroke                 ...                                                    No
11    Compression Ratio                 ...                                                    No
12        Turbo Charger                 ...                                                    No
13        Super Charger                 ...                                                    No

[14 rows x 3 columns]
```

ETC.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked absolutely fine. However there is a problem with the output. In the comparison from the website, if I give maruti Gypsy King Soft Top MPI BSIV & maruti omni E MPI STD BSIV, I'm not getting that specifications. Instead it is automatically giving Gypsy King Hard Top MPI BSIV & omni MPI Ambulance BSIV from that drop-down menu. I'm getting struggled with this as it is happening for all car models and specifications.